# Left-Linear and Right-Linear Grammar for a simple Regular Expression

Tags: grammar, regular-language, computation-theory

I am having trouble coming up with a left-linear and right-linear grammar for the following regular expression.

```
0(0+1)*+10^+
```

I am also quite confused on what the plus-closure does.

This is what I got for the left linear grammar, but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
    P: S--> 0A | 1A
       A--> A0|A1|0S|0| epsilon
```

Thank you!

Comment: "plus-closure" is similar to "star-closure", but instead of something repeating "0 or more times", it repeats "1 or more times".

Comment: What does `^` denote?

Comment: What are the scopes of your plus- and star-closures?

Comment: I meant the (^+) to be the plus closure for (10)

Comment: And the other pluses are "or"s?  I assume the first one is just "0 or 1"; what does the other cover?

Comment: @ScottHunter, it should be union

Comment: union of 0(0+1)* and 10^+

Comment: Your LL grammar in incomplete; it doesn't allow for any repetitions of `10`, as the plus-closure requires.

Comment: S > 1A > 10S > 100A > 100 -- oops.

Answer (score 2):

One general good way to find left- and right-linear grammars is to find an NFA that has the same language as your regex, then convert that NFA into a left- or right-linear grammar using the following mechanical transform:

- For each state q, introduce a nonterminal T<sub>q</sub>.
- For each transition (q, r) on character a (or where a = ε), add the production T<sub>q</sub> → aT<sub>r</sub> (for left-linear grammars) and T<sub>r</sub> → T<sub>q</sub>a (for right-linear grammars).

Then, for left-linear grammars:

- For each accepting state q, add the production T<sub>q</sub> → ε
- For left-linear grammars with start state q<sub>0</sub>, make the start symbol the symbol T<sub>q<sub>0</sub></sub>.

Then, for right-linear grammars:

- Add a start symbol S with the production S → T<sub>q</sub> for each accepting state q.
- Add the production T<sub>q<sub>0</sub></sub> → ε for the start state q<sub>0</sub>.

Try applying this idea here and you'll end up producing left- and right-linear grammars for your language. They might not be the most *efficient* grammars, but they'll work.